# Applescript: Change user password?

Tags: macos, shell, applescript

Trying to change user password through applescript.

```
do shell script "dscl . -passwd /Users/username oldpass newpass"
```

Doesn't seem to work on Mountain Lion. I get the following:

```
error "<dscl_cmd> DS Error: -14009 (eDSUnknownNodeName)" number 185
```

I've searched quite a bit, found nothing, now asking here.

Thanks.

Comment: Facing same error.. any help is appreciable

Answer (score 0):

It still works for me, but did you just forget to replace `username` with an actual username?

Comment: Yes i replaced with my username but still it is showing same error